# Lambda Expression Example

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Could someone show me an "traditional" example of a calculation e.g. find average of peoples age, using a loop method and then an example using a lambda expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see

```
class People
{
  int Age {get;set;}
};

var people = new List<People>() {...};
```

method loop

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(var p in people)
 sum += p.Age;
int average = sum / people.Count;
```

lambda

```
int average = people.Average(p => p.Age);
```

Comment: wow quite a difference..

Comment: yes. lambda are a powerful feature. that's why they have been added to .NET and now C++

Answer (score 1):

```
class Human
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Human> people = ...
int age = people.Average(p => p.Age);
```

Comment: abatishchev@ Do you know how to do the "traditional" method as well, e.g. using a loop?

Comment: @Den: Try [to find it yourself](http://www.google.ru/search?q=c%23+average+-linq) ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ages = new int[] { 10, 12, 14 };
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;

// loop
foreach (var age in ages) {
    count++;
    sum += age;
}
var average = sum / count;

// lambda
ages.Average(x => x); // this is where it'd be something like x.age if it was an array of objects instead of ints
```